# Tkinter "Open" Window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to replicate the "Open" button (For example on notepad to open a txt file) but I want to have it as a button beside entry in a tkinter window so I could either enter a directory or use button to select a specific folder.

```
import glob
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

for file in os.listdir(r"C:\directory"):
    print(file)

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

def inital():
        pass

#Making Widgets
frameT = Frame(root)
frameT.pack(side=TOP)
frameB = Frame(root)
frameB.pack(side=BOTTOM)

labelstart = Label(frameT, text="Configure")
labelstart.grid()
dirlabel = Label(frameT, text="Directory:")
dirlabel.grid(row=1)
dirinput = Entry(frameT)
dirinput.grid(row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok, you've told us what you want, but you haven't asked a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: Im trying to make a button that opens a Windows "Open" window that allows you select a folder like you would when opening a project in PyCharm for example. How would I do that? I thought it was pretty obvious. Its ok not to know yourself.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

def askopenfile():
        # If you want to browse files.
        path_to_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() # for a file
        # If you want to browse directories.
        path_to_folder = tkFileDialog.askdirectory() # for a directory
        print "File: " + path_to_file
        print "Folder: " + path_to_folder 

root = Tk()
b = Button(root, text="CLICK ME", command=askopenfile)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Hopefully this will help you, Yahli.